# To use hidden field value in another aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code i have a hidden value in sample.ascx and i want to use that value in sample.aspx in its codebehind.pls help me to do this.

Sample.ascx

```
txthidd.Value = "Hai";
<asp:HiddenField ID="txthidd" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Public property in your `ascx` like this

```
public string txt
{
  get
  {
    return this.txthidd.Value;
  }
}
```

and can access this in `aspx` like this

```
string textOnAspx = UC_UserControl.txt;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the codebehind, you should create a property getting the field:

```
public string TxtHidText{
    get 
    {
        return txthidd.Value;
    }
}
```

Then, you'll reference it per the id, let's say you'll have something like this in ASPX:

```
<u1:Sample id="SomeSampleContentOfThePage" />
```

and in codebehind, it will be accessible via

```
var text = SomeSampleContentOfThePage.TxtHidText;
```

Note that if you want to set it from the other aspx, you should create a set part as well.